# "https://sforgcompare.herokuapp.com/"Is this trusted tool for Salesforce org comparing sandbox to sandbox and sandbox to production

Tags: community, administration, security, tools

"https://sforgcompare.herokuapp.com/" is this trusted tool, any other tools for org comparing in Salesforce.
Your comments/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: There is a link to source code. If you want to be absolutely sure -- you can do an audit of that, and run your own instance to be 100% sure that it does only what is supposed to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purna:
There are a few products that can help you with Org comparison. For example, if you use Workbench or ANT (Metadata Deployment tool), you can retrieve the Org metadata as XML and use a file compare tool like BeyondCompare to figure out the differences. It is free/ cheap and it will work.

If you need a dead simple tool, please check out Snapshot. Disclaimer: I work for Metazoa, the maker of Snapshot. This can take a full Org metadata backup and help you with your Org comparison use case and many more.

Good luck with your search.

Sridhar

Comment: Hey..Thanks @Sridhar this is very helpful